# compatibility issues for Tensorflow federated in Google colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-federated

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
5 import numpy as np
6 import tensorflow as tf
----> 7 import tensorflow_federated as tff

14 frames
/usr/lib/python3.8/typing.py in _type_check(arg, msg, is_argument)
147         return arg
148     if not callable(arg):
--> 149         raise TypeError(f"{msg} Got {arg!r:.100}.")
150     return arg
151

TypeError: Callable[[arg, ...], result]: each arg must be a type. Got Ellipsis.

I'm getting this error while trying to import tensorflow_federated in Colab.

I have tried installing lower compatible versions of tensorflow and tensorflow_federated, but nothing works. Can someone else also faced this problem? and Do anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try again by installing the upgraded version of the TensorFlow Federated using the code below:

`pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated`

and then import TensorFlow Federated as below:

```
import tensorflow_federated as tff
print(tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'Hello, World!')())
print(tff.__version__)
```

Output:

```
b'Hello, World!'
0.56.0
```

Please have a look at this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification#before_we_start) for your reference.